# How to get the list of all the Members in IAM using Google API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-iam

I was trying to get the list of member and their role , I am able to find using command   but I need API, any help here?

related command : `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <name of the project>`

Comment: This is the service to use: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies REST API: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/searchAllIamPolicies

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Resource Manager REST API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy).

The response would be similar to:

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "etag": "someTag=",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/cloudtasks.admin",
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:name@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "user:username@domain.tld"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/firebase.admin",
      "members": [
        "user:username@domain.tld"
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

A single user may have multiple roles and that user's email may be in multiple items in bindings array but you should be able to filter them easily programmatically.

A Javascript function to get an array of users with their roles:

```js
const {bindings} = {} // response from API
const users = {}

bindings.forEach(({members, role}) => {
  members.forEach(member => {
    const [type, id] = member.split(":")
    if (!users[id]) users[id] = {roles: [], id, type}
    users[id]["roles"].push(role)
  })
})

const data = Object.keys(users).map(u => users[u])

console.log(data)

// Output:
[
  {
    id: "name@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    roles: ["roles/cloudtasks.admin"],
    type: "serviceAccount"
  },
  {
    id: "username@domain.tld",
    roles: ["roles/cloudtasks.admin", "roles/firebase.admin"],
    type: "user"
  }
]
```

Comment: @user3256289 glad to hear that. If my answer was useful you can accept it by clicking the checkmark icon beside it :)

Comment: I am, not eligible to do that ....it saying ....Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: @user3256289 you are probably talking about upvote. you can still accept the answer ;)  [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)